# use appcmd how to delete many applications

Tags: appcmd

I have known that using appcmd delete one app, for examle:

C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.ext delete app "sitename/appname"

but I want know use this command how to delete 2 or 3 applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I search and find that you can only delete one application by appcmd command once time .

the usage of appcmd command is as follows:

APPCMD delete APP [identifier] [-parameter1:value1 ...]

- identifier : need to delete application url

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I also find a lot of information that it can not delete more applications once time